# Ошибка с jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

На сайте есть поле, с суммой, которую можно менять ползунком, либо вводить вручную. При вводе числа вручную, ползунок больше нельзя двигать. 
В консоли ошибка:

```
closestHandle is undefined
```

Как можно решить проблему?

Библиотека стоит последней версии.

Comment: Вы ведь опытный посетитель этого сайта. Приведите хоть кусочек кода. Покажите, какие значения вводите.

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что ты вводишь НЕ `integer`. Попробуй прогнать через `parseFloat();`

Ещё, имей введу, что для такого бегунка, *jQuery UI* пользуется знаком % (проценты).